# Opencart's response class: redirect and setOutput

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have some code, where i need to make changes:

```
Pseudo:


index()
{
      if(method POST)
      {
        doSomething();
        $this->response->redirect(here the expression, what forming the URL of this page);
      }

      ** here creating $data for *.tpl **

      $this->response->setOutput($tpl_file, $data));
}
```

This code works well. But i cant understand, if every time when index called by method POST, page must load without $data and $tpl, but it wont.

Or when "redirect" caused, index would call second time and then "if(post)" doesnt trigger?

Comment: I can't really understand the question ...

Comment: Its ok. Just have some problems with understanding methods, cause OCart havent any documentation. I have solved my problem.

Comment: In future you should probably use the OpenCart forums: https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=190